# Taylor polynomials/series

Tags: analysis

I have this question:

> Write $x^5$ as a polynomial in $(x-3)$.

I’m not really sure how to proceed with answering it- I have a feeling you might need to use Taylor’s theorem somehow, as this is what we have recently covered

Comment: Just find derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor's theorem, with $f(x)=x^5$:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^5 f^{(k)}(3) \frac{(x-3)^k}{k!}$$
as $\forall k \geq 6$, $f^{(k)}=0$.

---

An other option is to notice that $x^5=((x-3)+3)^5$ and use a binomial expansion.

Comment: Can I leave it as that or do I have to multiply it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply it out" ?

Comment: Do I have to do anything else to it afterwards, like find individual terms? Or is that format okay?

Comment: I don't know :-). The individuals terms are not that hard to explicitly compute:
$$x^5=(x-3)^5+5\times 3 (x-3)^4+10 \times 3^2 (x-3)^3+10 \times 3^3 (x-3)^2+5 \times 3^4(x-3)+3^5$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Let $u=x-3$, then $x=u+3$:
$$
\begin{align}
x^5
&=(u+3)^5\\
&=\binom{5}{5}u^5+\binom{5}{4}3^1u^4+\binom{5}{3}3^2u^3+\binom{5}{2}3^3u^2+\binom{5}{1}3^4u^1+\binom{5}{0}3^5
\end{align}
$$
However, if you've just covered [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) in class, try writing that out and let $a=3$ so that the terms look like $(x-3)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to write $x^5$ as a summation of powers of $(x-3)$, i.e. $$x^5 = a_0 + a_1(x-3) + a_2(x-3)^2 + \ldots a_5(x-3)^5.$$

One way of brute force is to expand the RHS and solve the resulting linear system of 6 equations and 6 unknowns.

Another, perhaps more clever, is to expand $x^5$ into Taylor series around $x=3$.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘around x=3’? @gt6989b

Comment: @AIN you expand functions in Taylor series around a specific point...